# URL redirection with MD5 Value using javascript

Tags: javascript, url

I cant seems to get this function working.. the idea is to pass few variable entered in contact form and goes to online payment page. The problem is to get the MD5 value by combining the price, OrderID, .ndcorporate which is the merchant id and verifykey. This value will be assigned to vcode. Any clue?

```
function my_redirect() {
        var verifykey = "1b469d0628a34gt3989676084bad9626";
            var price = document.getElementById('get-amount').value;
        var orderID = document.getElementById('get-orderid').value;
        var vvcode = md5('+price+'.ndcorporate.'+orderID+'.'+verifykey+');
            var url = 'https://www.onlinepayment.com.my/MOLPay/pay/ndcorporate/? amount='+price+'&orderid='+orderID+'&vcode='+vvcode+'';
            window.location = url;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In JavaScript:

- the concatenation operator is `+` not `.`
- your variables need to be *outside* your string literals

Given `y = "Y"` and `z = "Z"`, ff you are trying to turn `y` and `z` into `"YZ"` then `y + z` not `'+y+'.'+z+'`.

Comment: assuming price = 100.00, orderid = 123abc
would that mean it should be 
`md5(100.00 + ndcorporate + 123abc + verifykey);`?

Comment: No, `md5( price + ndcorporate + orderid + verifykey )`.

Comment: How to get the MD5() returning the correct value? If in php its something like md5($amount.$merchantID.$orderID.$verifyKey). Sorry i'm not well verse inboth language either

Comment: Still `md5( price + ndcorporate + orderid + verifykey )`